# Regex java exception exclude "Caused by:"

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to capture the Java exception anem from a log file, but I would like to exclude the "Caused by:" string using **Oniguruma Regular Expressions Version 6.0.0**:

```
^.+Exception
```

returns:

```
"Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"
```

How can I write a regular expression which captures the exception name but ignores the "Caused by: " string in front of it? This will be used in Grok Logstash.

Comment: And what about `^(?!.*Caused by:).+Exception`? It should work.

Comment: not working, tested on http://rubular.com/r/JFI3pukx4y

Comment: It is working, as it does not match the line that contains `Caused by:`, as you wrote *I am trying to capture the Java exception from a log file without the "Caused by:" string*. If it is not what you really are doing, please update the question.

Comment: Yes but that means that I want to capture the java exception name but not the "Caused By: " string. i need the regex to only return "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"

Comment: That should be part of the question, not a comment. Use `(?<=^Caused by: ).+Exception`. Or, if you can access the capture group, use `^Caused by:\s*(.+Exception)`. Where are you using the regex? Grok/Logstash? Java?

Comment: Grok+Logstash, it keeps capturing the "Caused by" for some reason

Comment: Ok, I added the tags and an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use *capturing* with the following pattern:

```
^Caused\s*by:\s*(?<exception>[\w.]+)
```

The `(?<exception>[\w.]+)` named capturing group will match and *capture* into Group "exception" (creating the variable with the same name) 1+ word (letters, digits or underscores) or `.` chars.

Answering your question, to check and require something but excluding it from the  match, you may use lookarounds:

```
(?<=^Caused by: ).*?Exception
```

See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/zl7z90IO9l). And below is a test at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/:

[image]

Comment: Hi Wiktor thanks for the solution! I am having 2 values generated in the grok debugger, with and without the caused by string for some reason. {
  "exception": [
    [
      "Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"
    ],
    [
      "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: And if you use `(?<exception>(?<=^Caused by: ).*?Exception)`?

Comment: still returns 2 values but both are correct. {
  "exception": [
    [
      "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"
    ],
    [
      "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: Please check your other settings. BTW, you are only using 1 set of parentheses around the pattern, right?